# code not working in firefox

Tags: php, html

Code shown below is working in chrome and IE, but not in firefox

```
<img src="images\<? echo $photo_link;?>">
```

here `$photo_link` will have values like user.jpg and images is the folder containing images.

Comment: what if you replace the backslash with a forward slash?

Comment: I'd suggest using forward slashes for path resolution. All OSs can interpret the `/`, even Windows. If you moved your code to a non-windows server you might get some surprises.

Comment: More than that: Only forward slashes are allowed as separator in _URLs_. When browsers accept `\` it's because they are nice to windows users ;)

Comment: i dont get the relation ship between the PHP(server side) and the browser, they all will be a plain HTML no ???

Comment: @Qchmqs the html created by the php is invalid because of the backslash. The php has nothing to do with it. Firefox is simply not correcting the developer's URL mistake, where other browsers are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your backslash (`\`) to a forward slash (`/`) because those are the slashes that are supposed to be used in web addresses.

Browsers such as Internet Explorer fix the mistake of using backslashes for you, but FireFox does not. Consequentially, FireFox does not resolve your image path correctly.

**Corrected Code:**

```
<img src="images/<? echo $photo_link;?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use forward slashes (that being / ) in your URLs, not backslash.

```
<img src="images/<? echo $photo_link;?>">
```